# Placement of 3D Unity object on terrain

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I know how to instantiate an object; however, I have created a terrain that is not flat and am implementing physics on all objects. I will be spawning objects at locations but they need to be initialized on top of the terrain (not above). I can use a raycast from a very high y-axis position and cast downward to see for an intersection with the terrain and then use that position + half of the object y-dimension (so that it sits on top of the terrain); however, the terrain is oddly shaped and if the piece of terrain I want to put the object on is shaped concavely upward, part of the object that I create will be underneath the ground. Another way I have been thinking is to create the object quite a bit above the terrain and allow gravity to drop it down to the height where it sits on top of the terrain naturally; however, this sucks... I want it to be immediate and I think that there definitely should be a better way of doing this than what I have in mind.

ASCII Drawing:

```
       ______
      |      |
      |      |
      |______|
         |
-        |
  -      |     -
    -    |    -
      -  |   -
      * -V  -*
          --
```

The Box represents the object, the hyphens below represent the terrain underneath. The * represents the potential overlapping volume of the object with the terrain.

The line above ending with a 'V' represents the raycast. It checks the height at that particular point as it takes in only a Vector3 as an input. If I place the object (with an offset) so that the bottom surface of the object touches the point below the 'V', the lower edges will still be going through the terrain.

Comment: Using gravity and a position not too high above the terrain should be easier

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the actual shape the object you want to drop is, but a potential solution would be to imagine a bounding box (or actually create one) that encloses your entire object. You could then cast a ray from each of the bottom corners, and use the highest point on the terrain from those 4 rays to determine where to place your object. One way to accomplish that would be to get the -y extent of your object and project it from the +x/+z, +x/-z, -x/-z, -x/+z extents.
This of course may not be the most accurate solution for all object shapes (like an upside-down cone), but hopefully leads you in the right direction!

Another (simpler but maybe dirtier) approach would be to place the object like you did before, check for a collision, if the object is still colliding inch it up a bit, check for a collision again, and continue doing this until there is no longer a collision.